# Filter Query On DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, oledb

I'm trying to build a Multi-parameter query to filter information on a `DataGridView`. The following code has been generated using the QUERY WIZARD on Visual Studio.

The problem I'm experiencing is that the code doesn't fail, but never returns a result. I'm fairly certain that the issue is with the Booleans that are being used at the end of the query, but I'm not entirely sure.

I call my code for filtering like so:

```
Private Sub FILTER_Accept_Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FILTER_Accept_Button.Click
    Try
        Me.SparesTableAdapter.RunFilter(Me.Spares_DatabaseDataSet.Spares, Name_Of_PersonToolStripTextBox.Text, Site_NameToolStripTextBox.Text, Filter_Supplier_textbox.Text, FilterPartNo.Text, FilterJobNo.Text, FilterOrdered.Checked, FilterInvoiceRecieved.Checked, FilterPaidInvoices.Checked, FilterReceivedItems.Checked, FilterUrgent.Checked)

    Catch ex As System.Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The above code calls the `RunFilter` function:

```
Public Overridable Overloads Function RunFilter(ByVal dataTable As Spares_DatabaseDataSet.SparesDataTable, ByVal Name_Of_Person As String, ByVal Site_Name As String, ByVal Spares_Supplier As String, ByVal Part_Number As String, ByVal SAP_Job_Number As String, ByVal Date_Ordered As Boolean, ByVal Invoice_Received As Boolean, ByVal Invoice_Paid As Boolean, ByVal Date_Item_Received As Boolean, ByVal Marked_As_Urgent As Boolean) As Integer
            Me.Adapter.SelectCommand = Me.CommandCollection(6)
            If (Name_Of_Person Is Nothing) Then
                Me.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters(0).Value = Global.System.DBNull.Value
            Else
                Me.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters(0).Value = CType(Name_Of_Person, String)
            End If
            If (Site_Name Is Nothing) Then
                Me.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters(1).Value = Global.System.DBNull.Value
            Else
                Me.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters(1).Value = CType(Site_Name, String)
            End If
            If (Spares_Supplier Is Nothing) Then
                Me.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters(2).Value = Global.System.DBNull.Value
            Else
                Me.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters(2).Value = CType(Spares_Supplier, String)
            End If
            If (Part_Number Is Nothing) Then
                Me.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters(3).Value = Global.System.DBNull.Value
            Else
                Me.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters(3).Value = CType(Part_Number, String)
            End If
            If (SAP_Job_Number Is Nothing) Then
                Me.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters(4).Value = Global.System.DBNull.Value
            Else
                Me.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters(4).Value = CType(SAP_Job_Number, String)
            End If
            If (Date_Ordered = False) Then
                Me.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters(5).Value = CType("", String)
            Else
                Me.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters(5).Value = CType("Not Completed", String)
            End If
            If (Invoice_Received = False) Then
                Me.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters(6).Value = CType("", String)
            Else
                Me.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters(6).Value = CType("Not Completed", String)
            End If
            If (Invoice_Paid = False) Then
                Me.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters(7).Value = CType("", String)
            Else
                Me.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters(7).Value = CType("Not Completed", String)
            End If
            If (Date_Item_Received = False) Then
                Me.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters(8).Value = CType("", String)
            Else
                Me.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters(8).Value = CType("Not Completed", String)
            End If

            If (Marked_As_Urgent = False) Then
                Me.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters(9).Value = CType(False, Boolean)
            Else
                Me.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters(9).Value = CType(Marked_As_Urgent, Boolean)
            End If

            If (Me.ClearBeforeFill = True) Then
                dataTable.Clear()
            End If
            Dim returnValue As Integer = Me.Adapter.Fill(dataTable)
            Return returnValue
        End Function
```

The Query that is being used (in the `Me.CommandCollection(6)`):

```
"SELECT ID, [Name Of Person], [SAP Job Number], [Site Name], [Asset Description], [Spares Supplier], [Supplier Contact Name], [Supplier Contact Phone Number], [Supplier Contact Email], [Spares Description], [Part Number], [Quantity To Order], Cost, Comments, [Request Date], [Date Ordered], [Ordered By], [Invoice Received], [Invoice Paid], [Method Of Payment], [Date Item Received], [Quote Attatchment], [Marked As Urgent]  FROM Spares  WHERE ([Name Of Person] LIKE ? + '%') AND ([Site Name] LIKE ? + '%') AND ([Spares Supplier] LIKE ? + '%') AND ([Part Number] LIKE ? + '%') AND ([SAP Job Number] = ?) AND([Date Ordered] = ?) AND ([Invoice Received] = ?) AND ([Invoice Paid] = ?) AND ([Date Item Received] = ?) AND ([Marked As Urgent] = ?)"
```

Perhaps the above query is incorrect in some fashion? Any pointers would be great.

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**

I have updated my code, I've decided to just write my own filter string:

```
Public Sub Call_Filter()

    Dim myCon = New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.Database_string)

    Try
        myCon.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Sorry, An Error Occurred" & vbNewLine & _
               "Database Not Found!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
               "Error Message: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Could Not Locate Database")
        Main.VIEW_SavingMessage.Visible = False
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    Dim SQRText As String = "SELECT ID, [Name Of Person], [SAP Job Number], [Site Name], [Asset Description], [Spares Supplier], [Supplier Contact Name], [Supplier Contact Phone Number], " & _
                             "[Supplier Contact Email], [Spares Description], [Part Number], [Quantity To Order], Cost, Comments, [Request Date], [Date Ordered], [Ordered By], [Invoice Received], " & _
                             "[Invoice Paid], [Method Of Payment], [Date Item Received], [Quote Attatchment], [Marked As Urgent] " & _
    "FROM Spares " & _
    "WHERE ([Name Of Person] = @NameOfPerson OR @NameOfPerson = '' OR @NameOfPerson IS NULL) AND " & _
    "([SAP Job Number] = @SAPJobNo OR @SAPJobNo = '' OR @SAPJobNo IS NULL)"


    Dim sqr As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(SQRText, myCon)

    sqr.Parameters.Add("@NameOfPerson", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Main.Name_Of_PersonToolStripTextBox.Text
    If Main.FilterJobNo.Text <> "" Then
        sqr.Parameters.Add("@SAPJobNo", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Main.FilterJobNo.Text
    Else
        sqr.Parameters.Add("@SAPJobNo", OleDbType.Integer).Value = DBNull.Value
    End If

    Try
        Dim command = sqr.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Sorry, An error occured!" & vbNewLine & _
   "The database rejected the Delete request" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
   "Error Message: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Database Refused Parameterised Query")
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    Main.SparesTableAdapter.Fill(Main.Spares_DatabaseDataSet.Spares)


    myCon.Close()

End Sub
```

This works, but doesn't update the `Datagridview1` that is bound to the `SparesTableAdapter` when filled. Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: if your tables does not contain hundreds thousands of rows, fill a DataTable and bind it to DataGridView through a BindingSource. Then use the filter property of the BindingSource (same syntax as a SQL WHERE clause.

Comment: your query has 10 conditions with 2 of them being Dates.  have you pasted the resulting query into access to see if any rows are returned?  The fact that the Date params are passed as String does not bode well.

Comment: @Plutonix the query does not return anything. The dates are actually in string format in the database as they don't always contain Date values

Comment: I have updated the question with new code